# sed and sudo with string replace

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sudo

I want to replace a string with sed and save changes to same file which needs sudo as its a root owned file.

But while doing that I am getting below error

```
raja@raja-UbuntuVM:~$ sudo sed 's|gateway 192.168.56.1| |g' /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.56.102
        netmask 255.255.255.0

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
raja@raja-UbuntuVM:~$ sudo sed 's|gateway 192.168.56.1| |g' /etc/network/interfaces > /etc/network/interfaces
-bash: /etc/network/interfaces: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo sed 's|gateway 192.168.56.1| |g' /etc/network/interfaces > /etc/network/interfaces
```

That fails because your current (non-`sudo`) shell attempts to open the `interfaces` file before `sudo` is executing.  To work around this, use the `-i` (inplace edit) option of `sed`:

```
sudo sed -i 's|gateway 192.168.56.1| |g' /etc/network/interfaces
```

edits and replaces the file at the same time.

Comment: Worse, even if the perms allowed you to `> /etc/network/interfaces`, it would have erased the contents of the file because the shell redirection happens **before** the `sed` command is run...`sed` would have an empty input file and produce an empty output file.  That's why you have to use `-i` for in place edits, or a tmpfile if your version of `sed` doesn't support `-i`.

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that the `sudo` applies to the command (`sed`) but not to the redirection.  The redirection is happening in your shell, which is running as you (and you don't have permission to overwrite that file).  Which is a good thing in this case, otherwise you would have wiped `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Both cas and Robert Thank you for clear explanation .

Comment: The comment by cas above is crucial—never use a redirect to try to edit a file in place—but for a case where you want to run a bunch of arbitrary commands in a pipeline and pipe the result to a privileged file, the command `tee` is worth knowing.  `pipeline_of_commands | sudo tee privileged_file`

Comment: And for editing a file in place with arbitrary commands (which unlike `sed` may not have a flag for it), the best answer I've seen is http://serverfault.com/a/547331/313521

Comment: @Wildcard - its still a pipe, though, and so it isn't bottomless, and a full buffer in a situation like that locks the shell - which is the only place the data is kept. it is still good - i do it like that a lot, but i prefer here documents because they're usually backed by on-disk files: `sed -e\#script <<IN >infile\n$(cat <infile)\nIN\n` which is pretty much the same thing, but the buffer is seekable and is backed by a file on-disk - so `cat` can fill it as soon as it wants to. kinda reversed: `input | tee file | dd bs="$(sed '/pattern/q' | wc -c)" seek=1 if=/dev/null of=file"`